# Setting DBSecurityGroupIngress in Troposphere

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation, troposphere

Want to add Multiple CIDRIp to my DB security group
ERROR:

```
CidrIp=Ref(AppSecurityGroup)),
TypeError: __init__() takes at least 2 arguments (1 given)
```

I think this is very easy but i am stuck at here and confused.

```py
DBSecurityGroup = t.add_resource(
    rds.DBSecurityGroup(
        'DBSecurityGroup',
        GroupDescription='Enable access on the inbound port',
        DBSecurityGroupIngess=[
            rds.DBSecurityGroup(
                IpProtocol='tcp',
                FromPort='3306',
                ToPort='3306',
                CidrIp=Ref(AppSecurityGroup)),
            rds.DBSecurityGroup(
                IpProtocol='tcp',
                FromPort='3306',
                ToPort='3306',
                CidrIp=Ref(CalcSecurityGroup)),
            rds.DBSecurityGroup(
                IpProtocol='tcp',
                FromPort='3306',
                ToPort='3306',
                CidrIp=Ref(CIDRSupport))],
        VpcId=Ref(VPC),
        Tags=Tags(
            Name=Join("", [Ref("AWS::StackName"), "-DB-SG"]),
        )
    ))
```

Now i need to inbound to Calc-SG, App-SG and CIDRSupport on `6379` port.

How can I define it with in the SG ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are addressing a property `CidrIp` the `DBSecurityGroup` class does not have. This class is defined as:

```py
class RDSSecurityGroup(AWSProperty):
    props = {
        'CIDRIP': (basestring, False),
        'EC2SecurityGroupId': (basestring, False),
        'EC2SecurityGroupName': (basestring, False),
        'EC2SecurityGroupOwnerId': (basestring, False),
    }   

class DBSecurityGroup(AWSObject):
    resource_type = "AWS::RDS::DBSecurityGroup"

    props = {
        'EC2VpcId': (basestring, False),
        'DBSecurityGroupIngress': (list, True),
        'GroupDescription': (basestring, True),
        'Tags': ((Tags, list), False),
    }
```

From the source code [here](https://github.com/cloudtools/troposphere/blob/b50c67110b6e006d26728155238ba37c797c9710/troposphere/rds.py#L306-L323).

What you want to say is:

```py
DBSecurityGroup = t.add_resource(
    rds.DBSecurityGroup(
        "DBSecurityGroup",
        GroupDescription="Enable access on the inbound port",
        DBSecurityGroupIngress=[
            rds.RDSSecurityGroup(EC2SecurityGroupId=Ref(AppSecurityGroup)),
            rds.RDSSecurityGroup(EC2SecurityGroupId=Ref(CalcSecurityGroup)),
            rds.RDSSecurityGroup(EC2SecurityGroupId=Ref(CIDRSupport))],
        EC2VpcId=Ref(VPC),
        Tags=Tags(
            Name=Join("", [Ref("AWS::StackName"), "-DB-SG"]),
        )
    ))
```

I would note that Troposphere's `RDSSecurityGroup` corresponds to the "[RDS Security Group Rule](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-properties-rds-security-group-rule.html)". The inconsistency in the naming is confusing.

Comment: This question has been significantly edited since I gave that answer.

Comment: Thanks @Alex But how do i define `DBSecurityGroupIngress': (list, True),`
Can you Example

Comment: Troposphere resources generally map to the underlying AWS resources so did you look here? https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-properties-rds-security-group.html

Comment: @Rajatjain, I have updated the answer to show you exactly how to do it.

Comment: While creating `DBSecurityGroup` I it didn't pop any error but also, it did not create security group under `VPC security group` section,

Comment: Did it create the AWS::RDS::DBSecurityGroup resource in the Cloudformation stack though?

Comment: Is the AWS::RDS::DBSecurityGroup resource in the Cloudformation template generated? It is for me when I try that code.

Comment: In Sack it says: 

----------------
 `11:06:57 UTC+0550 CREATE_COMPLETE AWS::RDS::DBSecurityGroup DBSecurityGroup 
11:06:56 UTC+0550 CREATE_IN_PROGRESS AWS::RDS::DBSecurityGroup DBSecurityGroup Resource creation Initiated
11:06:56 UTC+0550 CREATE_IN_PROGRESS AWS::RDS::DBSecurityGroup DBSecurityGroup `


------------------
___
As per the Event it created but it does not visible in `securityGroup`
 But i didn't find it in Security groups under VPC section

Comment: Have you read this https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/USER_WorkingWithSecurityGroups.html

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/187833/discussion-between-alex-harvey-and-rajat-jain).

Comment: Well Thanks @Alex Harvey for your advice and Suggestion I got to find what i actually had to.. :)